# No attribute precedence across different attribute sources?

Tags: chef-infra

I'am aware of the [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attribute_precedence/) and i'am also aware about the different [attribute sources](https://docs.chef.io/attribute_sources/)

What i really cannot wrap my had arround (for a long time now) how precedence is across sources. When reading [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attribute_precedence/) one would assume, that

1. attribute file: `default[:mykey]`, will be overriden by
2. recipe: `node.default[:mykey]` from the recipe, will be overriden by
3. recipe: `node.normal[:mykey]` from the recipe

While 1. and 2. are correct, 3. is not due to it being "a different source"... I cannot find a way which basically computes the value for one attribute across all sources, lets call it `node.computed(:mykey)`

I understand that

```rb
# assume that default[:mykey]=1 in attributes/test.rb

# echo node.default[:mykey] would be 1

node.default[:mykey]=2
# echo node.default[:mykey] would be 2


# echo node.normal[:mykey] would be empty
# echo node[:mykey] would be empty

node.normal[:mykey] = 'foo'
# echo node.normal[:mykey] would 'foo;
```

In my head, i always assume that `node[:mykey]` would fallback to `node.default[:mykey]` when `node.normal[:mykey]` is not set, but this is clearly not the case.

This said, there is no way to "override a default" using node attributes at all? In my recipe i have to decide if i want to use the "default source of attribute files" or the "node object attributes" .. but i cannot do something like

*Use default attributes as long as no node object attribute is overriding it* - there is no `getter` for that, seems like it is not planned by design.

Of course i could do this in my `attribute/file.rb`

```rb
default[:mykey] = node.normal.dig(:mykey) unless node.normal.dig(:mykey).nil?
```

Or that in my recipe

```rb
node.default[:mykey] = node.normal.dig(:mykey) unless node.normal.dig(:mykey).nil?
```

And the always use `node.default[:mykey]` in my recpie when `getting` it - but that smells like a missing a concept.

**My question:**

a) Is what i described by design and the reason is, that there is an alternative route / different concept?

b) What is the right concept for:
"I want to have default values for a recipe in `attributes/myvals.rb` and want to make them override-able using node-attributes

Comment: I really should change `node.default[:mykey] = node.normal.dig(:mykey) unless node.normal.dig(:mykey).nil?` to `node.default[:mykey] = node.dig(:mykey) unless node.dig(:mykey).nil?` in my question to not confuse the question be about `normal` only or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding an answer to share my understanding about Chef attributes and their precedence. **An attribute for the node is ultimately computed to the node object - `node['attr']`**. This is what we should use this instead of `node.default`, `node.normal`, to effectively use the precedence levels.

As you have mentioned, there are different *types of attributes*:

- default
- normal
- override

**Precedence logic 1:**

Each of these types have a precedence level *within themselves* based on where they are defined (`attributes/` < `recipes/` < environment <> role).

**Precedence logic 2:**

Then there is a precedence of `default < normal < override` (for the node attribute as a whole). And finally, the ones defined with `override` win in the end.

**So**

Value of `node.override['attr']` will not change the value of `node.default['attr']`, *but it will change* the final `node['attr']` value.

**Example**

To make it easier to explain, let's use the `override` attribute as it has the least levels of precedence (*only* precedence logic 1).

Defined in `attributes/`:

```rb
override['attr'] = 'baz'
```

Then change values in `recipes/`:

```rb
node.default['attr'] = 2

node.normal['attr'] = 'foo'

log node.default['attr']
#=> 2

log node.normal['attr']
#=> 'foo'

log node['attr']
#=> 'baz'
```

So we can see that even though recipe attributes have higher level of precedence, it doesn't impact the node attribute as it was defined with `override`. Same `override` attributes, defined in a Chef role or environment will have higher precedence than of recipe.

> a) Is what i described by design and the reason is, that there is an alternative route / different concept?

There is definitely a restriction between the three types of attributes. If I wanted to change a `node.default` attribute, I would have to go by Precedence logic 1.

If I wanted to change the overall node attribute, it could be a combination of precedence logic 1 and 2.

> b) What is the right concept for: "I want to have default values for a recipe in attributes/myvals.rb and want to make them override-able using node-attributes

To keep things simple and avoid the permutations and combinations of precedence logic 1 and 2, we can use `default` attributes in the `attributes/`, and then override them with `default`, `normal`, or `override` attributes from `recipes/`, environment, role. In the below example, I am using `default` attributes all the way.

Defined in `attributes/default.rb`:

```rb
default['cookbook']['attrib'] = 'foo'
```

If required, override it from recipe:

```rb
node.default['cookbook']['attrib'] = 'bar'
```

(at this point the value of the attribute will be `bar`)

Or, override it from role or environment:

```json
    "default_attributes": {
      "cookbook": {
        "attrib": "baz"
    }
```

And the final `node['cookbook']['attrib']` will be `baz`.

**Update:**

The [older documentation](https://docs-archive.chef.io/release/12-9/attributes.html) for Chef attributes says that the `node.normal` attributes are not reset at the beginning of the chef-client run, and hence are kind of persistent.

> Normal attributes are never reset.

Comment: my tests proove that `node[:attr]` is nothing more then a short for `node.normal[:attr]` thus in no way the computed value of `node.default[:attr]` against `node.normal[:attr]` - i would love to have that, but that is not the case. There is no getter which does this:

Comment: I understand that using the precendence inside one source is possible and i get your last example - but this only works out on paper. The problem is, when you use ktichen tests/chef zero/chef server, you adjust attributes (tune) them by node. When you do so, those attributes are in node.normal, not in node.default. Thus when the code uses node.default[] to get the value, while you tune it there, it will not be the desired outcome.

Comment: Ok there used to a mention about `normal` attributes not getting reset in earlier documentations, but it is not there in the recent ones for some reason. Will add that link in the answer if the primary focus of the question was on `normal` attribute (which didn't appear so).

Comment: Sorry for the series of comments. I just happen to notice that detail `"default_attributes"` when you talk about overrides. For me, that does not work out when using kitchen. `attributes` and `default_attributes` will end up in `node.normal`

Comment: `node.normal` attributes are not reset (persistent on node) at the beginning of Chef run. Not sure why the latest documentation doesn't have anything to say on that.

Comment: My statements are not really made uppon suggestions here. Chef 16 based tests i have no published here https://github.com/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib - more precisely this https://github.com/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/blob/master/test/cookbooks/kontextwork-helpers-lib-test/recipes/attribute_test.rb . I do both test runs using `attributes` or `default_attributes` - both end up like described before - they only affect the node.normal namespace, never node.default, thus override node.default view node attributes is not possible. ...

Comment: See the test runs, https://travis-ci.com/github/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/builds/217038883#L900 shows that `attributes` at https://github.com/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/blob/master/.kitchen.yml#L26 and https://travis-ci.com/github/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/builds/217039069#L1005 also proves that `default_attributes` https://github.com/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/blob/master/.kitchen.yml#L32 had no. Since `node.normal` is not set either, it's not working at all here (`default_attributes` not working)

Comment: Just in fact, `Normal attributes are never reset.` is still the case, what ever is set on `node.normal` will be persisted across all runs in will be set from the start in the next run. This does not really change what we have here though, since we run it once in the CI.

Comment: After adding more tests (no attribute overriding and via role default attributes) i can see that using `default_attributes` from roles would actually work the desired way. `node[]` is either the attribute `node.default`, or if a `default_attribute` has been set, it will override node. So what is somewhat suprising it that there is no way to do this with node-specific attributes ATM? I have to use a role or environment to change values for 1 specific node? https://travis-ci.com/github/KontextWork/chef-cookbook-kontextwork-helpers-lib/builds/217040541